# How to copy an entire content from a directory to another in Java?

Tags: java

```
File content[] = new File("C:/FilesToGo/").listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++){                       

    String destiny = "C:/Kingdoms/"+content[i].getName();           
    File desc = new File(destiny);      
    try {
        Files.copy(content[i].toPath(), desc.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
}
```

This is what I have. It copies everything just fine.
But among the contents there are some folders. The folders are copied but the folder's contents are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion. Here is a method the uses rescursion to delete a system of folders:

```
public void move(File file, File targetFile) {
    if(file.isDirectory() && file.listFiles() != null) {
        for(File file2 : file.listFiles()) {
            move(file2, new File(targetFile.getPath() + "\\" + file.getName());
        }
    }
    try {
         Files.copy(file, targetFile.getPath() + "\\" + file.getName(),  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Didn't test the code, but it should work. Basically, it digs down into the folders, telling it to move the item, if its a folder, go through all its children, and move them, etc.

Comment: But this would delete the sub-folders and copy their contents directly to the destiny, wouldnt it? I need to have the sub-folders as well.

Comment: This doesnt delete the sub-folders, the Files.copy method doesnt delete anything. It simply puts a copy of it in the new path

Comment: Nosuchfileexception 
C:\Source\subfolder\afile.txt -> C:\Kingdoms\Source\subfolder\afile.txt
It copied everything except the subfolder's content

Answer (score 3):

Would recommend using [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) in Apache Commons IO:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("C:/FilesToGo/"),
                        new File("C:/Kingdoms/"));
```

Copies directories & contents.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what needs to be changed in Alex Coleman's answer, for the code to work. Here is the modified version of Alex's code that I tested and that works fine for me:

```
private void copyDirectoryContents(File source, File destination){
    try {
        String destinationPathString = destination.getPath() + "\\" + source.getName();
        Path destinationPath = Paths.get(destinationPathString);
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }        
    catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        //UnsupportedOperationException
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException e) {
        //DirectoryNotEmptyException
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //IOException
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        //SecurityException
    }

    if(source.isDirectory() && source.listFiles() != null){
        for(File file : source.listFiles()) {               
            copyDirectoryContents(file, new File(destination.getPath() + "\\" + source.getName()));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old by now, but I wanted to share my copy methods using **java.nio.file**.

Copying source directory: **src** into a container directory: **dst**.

"Directory" is just a helper class. In this example you can think of it as "Path" container.

We separate the directory **structure** from the file **content**.
It's explicit, and easy to imagine. (Also, it avoids some potential Exceptions thrown by the Files.copy() method if you instead copied all files in "one go")

```
public static void copy(Directory src, Directory dst, boolean replace) throws IOException {
        if (src == null || dst == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        Path sourcePath = src.path();
        Path targetPath = dst.path().resolve(sourcePath.getFileName());
        copyStructure(sourcePath,targetPath);
        copyContent(sourcePath,targetPath,replace);
    }
```

I.e. we want to copy the folder "top" into the "dst" folder "container".

sourcePath = ...some/location/**top**

targetPath = ...another/location/container/**top**

**copyStructure:** Iterates through the source files. If the source file is a directory and the a target file with equivalent name does not exist, we create
the target folder. (So "copy" is not accurate. We "assure" structure)

```
private static void copyStructure(final Path source, final Path target) throws IOException {
        if (source == null || target == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        final String tarString = target.toString();
        final String srcString = source.toString();
        Files.walk(source).forEach(new Consumer<Path>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Path srcPath) {
                if (Files.isDirectory(srcPath)) {
                    String subString = srcPath.toString().substring(srcString.length());
                    Path newFolder = Path.of(tarString,subString);
                    if (!Files.exists(newFolder)) {
                        try { Files.createDirectory(newFolder);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now that we know that a target directory structure exists, we iterate the source files again. But now we only copy the "content" (regular files). Choosing whether to replace existing content. **copyContent:**

```
private static void copyContent(final Path source, final Path target, boolean replace) throws IOException {
        if (source == null || target == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        final String tarString = target.toString();
        final String srcString = source.toString();
        Files.walk(source).forEach(new Consumer<Path>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Path srcPath) {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(srcPath)) {
                    String subString = srcPath.toString().substring(srcString.length());
                    Path newFile = Path.of(tarString,subString);
                    if (!Files.exists(newFile)) {
                        try { Files.copy(srcPath,newFile);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (replace) {
                            try { Files.copy(srcPath,newFile,
                                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```